# How to make ForeignKey play nice with None in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Django REST Framework, is there an easy way to work with nullable ForeignKeys and serializers?  I keep running into issues (mainly in my tests) where I'll serialize a model that has a nullable foreign key, send the data back to DRF and I get the error 'Incorrect type.  Expected pk value, received str.'

Example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, null=True, blank=True)

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    model = Book
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

and the usual implementation with URLs, routes, and all that.

Then, in shell:

```
>>> from django.test.client import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> book = Book()
>>> serializer = BookSerializer(book)
>>> response = client.post('/books/', serializer.data)
>>> response.data
{'publisher': ['Incorrect type.  Expected pk value, received str.']}
```

Seems like this should work since the data being posted came directly from DRF's serializer.  Has anyone else encountered this?  What are the best practices here?

Comment: What happens if you define the field on the serializer explicitly with required=False?

Comment: explicitly defining the field with required=False does not change anything

Answer (score 2):

I assume this has something to do with the book instance not yet being associated with a saved `Publisher` instance.  I expect that if you'd actually created a saved published instance and associated that with the book instance then it would work as expected.

Note also that serialization won't perform an validation, only deserialization will do that, so `serializer.data` will still happily return a serialized instance.  Incidentally, what is the value of `serializer.data` in your example code?

**Edit**: Oh sorry, I may be being stupid - it is a *nullable* FK after all.  Same question holds, then... what is the value of `serializer.data` in your example code?

Link to this ticket on `django-rest-framework` repo: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1303

Comment: Hi Tom, this will fail also in a put request to an existing record (which I think indirectly answers your questions).  I've opened issue 1303 on GH with a few more details.